# Delete all data of all tables of all user databases in MariaDB

Tags: mariadb

In our development environment, we want to have a `DeleteData.sql` query that developers can use to delete all of the data of all tables of all databases of their MariaDB docker instance.

For example, let's say our developers work on a project that has 3 databases:

- Accounts
- Products
- Orders

And let's say each database has 10 tables. We want to run `DeleteData.sql` and delete data from all tables in these three databases.

We do this to give developers a tool to test different data sets both for performance testing and for data validation and consistency.

But we have no idea how we can achieve this. In SQL Server we would:

1. Use a cursor to loop over databases
2. Create delete statements for all tables of each database dynamically
3. Use `execute sp_executesql` to run that query dynamically on that database

Is it possible in MariaDB? Is there a better way to get to this result?

Comment: As far as in mysql/mariadb cursors are available only within stored procedures there is no difference between 1 and 3. I would use that approach 
 - `CALL truncate_tables( someuser )` - to truncate all the tables.

Comment: I'm not sure MariaDB has `sp_executesql`, did you mean to tag your database system as such? If so, maybe you meant [`EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/execute-immediate/)?

Comment: @J.D., that's for SQL Server. The problem with `execute_immediate` is that it seems that it only works inside a stored procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plan A:

Write a script to create the 30 `TRUNCATE` statements from `information_schema.TABLES` and put them in the script.

(Note: `TRUNCATE` is faster than `DELETE` and also it resets `AUTO_INCREMENT`, so it is better at going back to the start.)

Plan B:

Use `mysqldump --no--data` to generate the tables and, I think, all the `DROPs` needed.  (If not, preface with three `DROP DATABASEs`.)

Comment: Plan A is not dynamic. It can't be used for many applications with different sets of databases and tables. Thus that's not applicable. Plan B is interesting. In fact, Plan B is about deleting all databases first and then recreating their structure without data.

Comment: @SaeedNeamati - DROP + reCREATE is the fastest way.  (I think it is what `TRUNCATE` does.  Plan A can be dynamic -- if you construct the statements, then PREPARE and EXECUTE them.